# Get information about topic message at runtime

Tags: ros, python, rospy, messages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build an interface that universally bridges ROS topics to another system.
I am importing the message type at runtime:

```
importcom = (  # import type
    "from " +
    topic_class +
    ".msg import " +
    topic_type
)
exec(importcom, globals())
```

This allows me to later subscribe to this topic dynamically at runtime.

My question is now: **How can I gain insight in the structure of this message at runtime?** Ideally I need a json object that includes the types of all the parameters that i expect in a message. e.g.:

```
{
   "angular" :
      {
           "x": float
           "y": float 
   "linear" :
      {
           "x": float
           "y": float 
....
```

(or something like this)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221130/get-information-about-topic-message-at-runtime/) by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on ROS Answers with karma: 862 on 2015-11-18

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't know about any existing way to get json directly, but the output of [rosmsg show](http://wiki.ros.org/rosmsg) should be relatively easy to parse and transform into json. e.g.:

```
$ rosmsg show sensor_msgs/CameraInfo
Header header
  uint32 seq
  time stamp
  string frame_id
uint32 height
uint32 width
RegionOfInterest roi
  uint32 x_offset
  uint32 y_offset
  uint32 height
  uint32 width
float64[5] D
float64[9] K
float64[9] R
float64[12] P
```

And if you're into python, you can checkout the implementation of rosmsg [here](https://github.com/ros/ros_comm/blob/indigo-devel/tools/rosmsg/src/rosmsg/__init__.py)

---

Originally posted by [Dimitri Schachmann](https://answers.ros.org/users/22775/dimitri-schachmann/) with karma: 789 on 2015-11-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Justin_Qiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/35037/justin_qiu/) on 2018-05-09**:
Could you give some hints how to get the API of rosmsg? Because I found the API of rosgraph which can parse the information about which topics the nodes are subscribing from or publishing to. But I didn't find the API to access outputs of "$rosmsg show".

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is an API to get rosmsg through python: http://docs.ros.org/kinetic/api/rosmsg/html/

After import modules:

```
import rospy  
import rosmsg  
import rospkg
```

I can get the text of messages through `rosmsg.list_msgs(ros_pkg)` from a certain package, and get all the packages through `rospkg.RosPack().list()`

---

Originally posted by [Justin_Qiu](https://answers.ros.org/users/35037/justin_qiu/) with karma: 11 on 2018-05-14

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1